# How do I switch between Ubuntu and Vista and how do I delete Ubuntu?

Tags: removing, windows-vista

So I was wondering how do I switch between Windows Vista and Ubuntu? And also, if need to, how do I go about deleting Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Once you install Ubuntu alongside Windows, when you restart you'll see a screen that offers you a choice to boot into Ubuntu or Windows.  That screen is the interface for the Linux bootloader known as Grub, which will be installed by default when you install Ubuntu.

Removal of Ubuntu, as czifro mentioned above, would be a simple matter of deleting or formatting the partition which contains it.

Answer (score 0):

to switch between winV and ubuntu you use the grub2 bootloader. and to delete ubuntu, simply (in winV) use disk utility (click start menu -> R click computer -> click manage) to either format the ubuntu partition, or delete it, both remove ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

To delete Ubuntu from windows is easy, Click Start, click Run, type compmgmt.msc, and then click OK.In the console tree, click Disk Management. The Disk Management window appears. Now select the drive in which you have installed Ubuntu and format it. Thats it. But grub will still be there at the time of booting and it will show Ubuntu in it. Don't worry its just like a broken link!